# Is there a way to suppress MSBuild warnings in a specific subdirectory with .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, compilation, msbuild, warnings

I am gettings warnings from compiling my ASP.Net 6 Razor project, errors that are mainly linked to the lack of `<summary>` comments in my migrations folder.

I have tried to add the following `Directory.Build.props` file to my `.\Data\Migrations` folder as I had found somewhere that I could suppress warnings in that folder.

```xml
<Project>
 <PropertyGroup>
    <DisabledWarnings>CS1591;IDE0161</DisabledWarnings>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Yet, I keep getting the same errors:

```
1591: Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member 'CorrectedSpellingOf2FAEnabled' [<redacted>\3moons.csproj]
<redacted>\Data\Migrations\20220526151631_CorrectedSpellingOf2FAEnabled.cs(9,33): warning CS 
1591: Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member 'CorrectedSpellingOf2FAEnabled.Up(MigrationBuilder)' [<redacted>\3moons.csproj]

...
```

I have also tried to redact the warning labels:

```xml
 <PropertyGroup>
    <DisabledWarnings>1591;161</DisabledWarnings>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Alas, this doesn't work. The warnings are still present.

For reference my `.csproj` file is as follows:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <RootNamespace>Minustar.Website</RootNamespace>
        <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.5" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.5" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.5">
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      </PackageReference>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies" Version="6.0.5" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="6.0.5" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.5" />
      <PackageReference Include="Westwind.AspNetCore.Markdown" Version="3.8.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

My intuition is that there could be a way to suppress those warning, or any other, directly from the `.csproj` file but I am unsure how and where.

In advance, thank you.

PS:

I have also tried this, on @Ryan Wilson's suggestion, to read on the warning suppression page.

```cs
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Compiler", "CS1591", Target="N:Minustar.Website.Data:migrations", Scope="namespaceanddescendants")]
```

To no avail, I still get the messages in the compiler output, and both VSCode and VS2022 still list the issues as a warning. It did however seem to work for `[SuppressMessage("Compiler", "IDE0161")]` (this one suggests the use file-scoped namespace declaration instead of what the EF Core migrations tool emmits.)

I am still convinced that it is possible to achieve the desired result out-of-the box, so to speak, without any 3rd party tools; however, the solution evades me entirely.

PPS: Disabling the `GenerateDocumenationFile` option is preferably not an option.

Comment: MSDN - [suppress-warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/suppress-warnings) ???

Comment: I have tired using the `SuppressWarning` attribute, and it seems I am quite not understanding its usage.